# Machine Learning algorithm to learn submodular set functions

Tags: machine-learning, kernel-functions

I'm looking for some machine learning algorithm to train on data that are sampled from some submodular set function and I want the learned model predictions also obey submodularity.
For example linear regression can do this (because it's linear hence it produce a model that obey both submodularity and supermodularity) but I want a model that is not linear and can capture some non-linear relationships in the data.
I played with SVR (support vector regression) with some kernels but could not prove anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach is to train a model that is guaranteed, by the design of its architecture, to represent a submodular function.  The following research paper looks like it might be helpful for that:

[Deep submodular functions: Definitions and learning](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2016/file/7fea637fd6d02b8f0adf6f7dc36aed93-Paper.pdf).  Brian W. Dolhansky and Jeff A. Bilmes.  NeurIPS 2016.

---

Another possible approach might be to learn a set function, and then add a regularization/penalty term to the loss function to penalize any violations of submodularity.  There are various methods for learning a set function.  One very simple one, if the universe that the set is contained within is small enough, is to simply apply a one-hot encoding of the set, then feed that feature vector to a normal network.  If the universe is large, there are more sophisticated methods in the research literature, e.g.,

[Deep Sets](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2017/file/f22e4747da1aa27e363d86d40ff442fe-Paper.pdf).  Manzil Zaheer, Satwik Kottur, Siamak Ravanbhakhsh, Barnabás Póczos, Ruslan Salakhutdinov, Alexander J. Smola.  NeurIPS 2017.

[Set Transformer: A Framework for Attention-based Permutation-Invariant Neural Networks](http://proceedings.mlr.press/v97/lee19d.html).  Juho Lee, Yoonho Lee, Jungtaek Kim, Adam R. Kosiorek, Seungjin Choi, Yee Whye Teh.  Proceedings on Machine Learning Research.

Then, if $f_\theta(S)$ represents the value of the function on set $S$ (using parameters $\theta), we can introduce a penalty term as follows:

$$\Psi(\theta) = \max_{S,T} \max(f_\theta(S \cup T) + f_\theta(S \cap T) - f_\theta(S) - f_\theta(T),0).$$

Now add $\Psi(\theta)$ to the loss function, and then train as usual, with this modified loss function.  To make this work, you'll need to find a way to compute $\Psi(\theta)$, or at least to estimate it.  I'm not immediately sure how to do that, and it might depend on the specific model you use.